# a problem on functional equations

Tags: functions

if fuction is defined from $N to N$ then can we say that it is not continuous as it is not defined for all $x$??a simple statement ,but this is stopping me from giving the solution to a question..pls help

Comment: Do you mean $f:\mathbb N\rightarrow \mathbb N$? Every function with domain $\mathbb N$ with the usual topology is continuous because that topology is discrete.

Comment: please use some simple terms..im new to the topic..@MPW

Answer (score 0):

The definition of continuous is always relative.

If you have a function $\mathrm{f} : X \to Y$ between topological spaces $X$ and $Y$, then you need to know which topology you are using on the source $X$ and which topology you are using on the target $Y$ before you are able to decide if $\mathrm{f}$ is [continuous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function) or not.

We say that $\mathrm{f}$ is continuous if, for every open set $U \subseteq Y$, the set $\mathrm{f}^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$ with respect to the topology on $X$. Here $\mathrm{f}^{-1}(U) := \{ x \in X : \mathrm{f}(x)\in U \}$.

If we take the so-called [discrete topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_space) on both $X$ and $Y$, i.e. *every* set in $X$ and $Y$ is open then it follows that *every* function $\mathrm{f} : X \to Y$ is continuous because for any set $U \subseteq Y$, the preimage $\mathrm{f}^{-1}(U)$ is a set in $X$ and, by definition of the discrete topology, is an open set.

If we take the so-called [trivial topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trivial_topology) on both $X$ and $Y$, i.e. *only* the whole set and the empty set are open, then the *only* continuous functions are those for which $\mathrm{f}(X)=Y$, i.e. surjections.

Comment: FYI, this "trivial topology" is known as the *indiscrete topology*.

Comment: @MPW I agree that that name is *sometimes* used.